# There are currently no power options available for some Windows users on a domain

Tags: windows, active-directory

In a Windows 2012 active directory domain that had been updated from a Windows SBS 2008 domain some users are not able to shutdown/restart their computers from the Windows 7 or Windows 10 start menus. Here are a few things I have checked.

1) Users that do work normally and users that do not work normally are members of the same Active Directory security groups.
2) With RSOP.msc all users are getting their group policy settings for the "Start Menu and Taskbar"from the same Group Policy (Default Domain).
3)SecPol reveals that User Right Assignments are same for all users.

I cannot find anything that is different between the users who can shutdown the computer from the start menu and those who cannot. The settings are the same no matter which domain computer they sign on to. It also does not matter if it is Windows 7, Windows 10 (1607) or Windows 10 (1703).
Work-arounds do work. The affected users can shutdown/restart from the command prompt and they can shutdown/restart after sighing out of Windows.
I suspect the Windows SBS 2008 origins of the domain have something to do with this only because of the total pain that OS has been since 2008! It continues to be a plague on the domain.

Comment: Please provide us a gpresult output, you can scramble personnal detail in it, but it will allow us to see if a gpo apply to the user/computer.

Comment: Sorry. Don't know how. But thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you could tell me specifically what you are looking for in the Group Policy.

Comment: If machines are running the latest Creators update it contains a bug which all workstations that run this version will get the message that there is no power options currently available. A fix hasn't come out for this yet. However the user can click the profile icon, click logout then from the login screen can restart, shutdown etc.